# Injective homomorphism on tensor product

Tags: modules, tensor-products

I am currently attempting the following:

> Find (cyclic) $\mathbb{Z}$-modules $M, N, P$ and an injective homomorphism $f: M \rightarrow N$ s.t. $g:  M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} P \rightarrow N \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} P$ is not injective.

I feel like there should be simple examples to show this, but I just can't seem to find anything.  I'm guessing that if I was to replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with a field, then the injectivity of $f$ would imply the injectivity of $g$, but I still can't seem to be able to figure out an example for this case!

Any hints / nudges would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Certainly, over a field, every module is flat, so your assertion about that case is correct. For a non-cyclic example, take $ f\!: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$ the inclusion, and $P = \mathbb Z/n$, for any $n \geq 2$.

Comment: For a cyclic example, take $f\! \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z,\ x \mapsto nx$, and $P = \mathbb Z/n$.